# JQuery fade out only working when typed in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple navigation bar that fades content in and out when clicked; however, my `fadeOut()` jQuery call simply doesn't cause my div element to fade while the alert is appearing. If I copy the `fadeOut()` line and paste it into the console, the element fades. Can anyone see why `fadeOut()` isn't working? Any help and tips are appreciated!

**`HTML`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link REL=stylesheet HREF="./styles/style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class=active id="home-btn" href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="about-btn" href="">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="./data/resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a id="contact-btn" href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home" style="margin-left:20%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
  <p>Hi, I'm Austin. Check out my site.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**`JS`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#about-btn" ).click(function() {
    $( "#home" ).fadeOut("slow");
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

**`CSS`**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
}

li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.active {
    background-color: #6b8d2f;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: alert is a blocking function. The page JS won't run until the alert is closed.

Comment: I only inserted that to ensure the click() function was running. Even without the alert, nothing fades.

Comment: why are you including 2 jquery versions?

Comment: remove that `alert()` or place it before `fadeOut()`. it works as normal

Comment: Whoops. Just tried them both individually, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @MuhammedShevilKP Interesting that it's working for you.. How are you hosting the site? I just have a directory saved, and I'm opening my index.html in Chrome. Do you think that might cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using a `click` event on an `a` element. You need to prevent the default event. Change your JS to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#about-btn" ).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // the new line
    $( "#home" ).fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to preventDefault in order to see the output

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#about-btn" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#home" ).fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
}

li a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.active {
    background-color: #6b8d2f;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a class=active id="home-btn" href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a id="about-btn" href="">About me</a></li>
  <li><a href="./data/resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a id="contact-btn" href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home" style="margin-left:20%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
  <p>Hi, I'm Austin. Check out my site.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello try this below jquery.Use Prevent default to prevent the button's default action  It will also works with alert! if you use before fadeout.If you use after the fadeout will work though but it wont't be much visilable
 .. hope it helps

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#about-btn" ).on('click',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 alert("clicked");
 $( "#home").fadeOut("slow");
 });
 });
```